# How can I force grep to only return files and ignore directories?

Tags: bash, unix, grep, locate

I'm trying to use grep to automatically locate the bibtex program in the user's bin folder.

The problem is, it frequently returns a directory with the name bibtex, which means that the script fails to automatically run the command.

How can I force grep (or indeed the locate command) to automatically ignore directories?

EDIT: The current command is: `locate bibtex | grep "/bibtex$" -d skip | head -n1`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `find` command?

```
find /bin -name bibtex -type f
```

Looks for a file name "bibtex" of type "f", which is a regular file.

Comment: icecreamhead, accept this answer immediately, as your search is over :-)

Comment: This answer does indeed work, but it takes much, much longer than locate, which isn't ideal in this situation

Answer (score 4):

```
locate --basename '\bibtex' --limit 1
```

Eliminates the need for `grep` and `head`, but still doesn't solve the issue of whether the result is a directory.

Why don't you do:

```
type -P bibtex
```

which will look in the `PATH` for a program by that name?

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand exactly so maybe my solution is wrong: why don't you use [which](http://linux.die.net/man/1/which)? Or *bibtex* isn't in *PATH*?

Answer (score 1):

*Sigh*, not my cleanest, but it works. `perl -ne 'chomp($f=$_);print if !-d $f'`

which makes your command `locate bibtex | perl -ne 'chomp($f=$_);print if !-d $f' | grep "/bibtex$" -d skip | head -n1`

Comment: `-d skip` performs no action here since the input to `grep` is `stdin`. You can shorten your command to `perl -ne 'chomp; print if ! -d'`

Comment: That was my first run of it, but I was unsure if the missing line-feeds would cause problems later down the pipe chain. I guess I'm a Nervous Nelly that way.

Comment: By the way, you can shorten that to `perl -lne 'print if !-d'` (the chomp doesn't seem to be necessary, if it were then `perl -lne 'chomp; print if !-d'`).